# C# Reflection Assembly: getMethods() ignores constructors

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor, .net-assembly

As said in title. I tried using Bindingflags but none of them seem to be working:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(somePath);
foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
             foreach(var method in type.GetMethods())
             Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
            }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because constructors are not methods (despite some superficial similarities in syntax). For constructors you want `Type.GetConstructors` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.type.getconstructors).